# Magento 2 Cart Price Rule is not working

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, elasticsearch

This is the first time I created a sales rule on the site, but it doesn't work. I want the shipping cost for a product to be free.

I have done the following:

1. Create the price rule in Marketing -> Promotions: Cart Price Rules with the following Options assigned:

   In Actions I have added the condition by product SKU and selected For matching items only in Free Shipping.

[image]

2. I have checked in the salesrule table that the rule is actually created.

[image]

3. The project is using Elasticsearch with the Elasticsuite module version ~2.9.0. I have seen that when reindexing for some the Sales Rule index appears, in my case it is not like that. Could this be the cause of the Cart Price Rule not working? How can I add Sales Rule to the indexing?

[image]

Magento 2.3.5 CE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cart price rule does not have Indexer in CE